# polar equation of the line y = x (in rectangular form) through the origin

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm using Mathematica and I'm trying to graph the polar equation

$$r = \frac k  {(\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))}$$

where k is an element of the integer and theta is the argument of the
function for which I let vary from 0 to 2pi.

If I assign any value to k except 0, I can definitively draw a line.
However whenever I'm trying to assign the value of 0 to k a cartesian plane appears with no graph in it whatsoever.

How come is this possible?

My goal is in fact to graph the equivalent of y = x (in rectangular form), but in a polar coordinate system.

Can someone is able to provide me the algebraic steps (if there is any) necessary to obtain such a graph in PolarPlot (the name of the command) using Mathematica?

Comment: Hey, but how to to it with the Mathematica command PolarPlot[{r = f(theta)},{theta, -2pi, 2pi}]?

Answer (score 1):

$x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$, hence the line $x=y$ is equivalent to $\cos\theta=\sin\theta$, which is same as the line $$\theta=\frac{\pi}4$$

Comment: Hey, but how to to it with the Mathematica command PolarPlot[{r = f(theta)},{theta, -2pi, 2pi}]?

Comment: It will just be a line parallel to the $r$-axis

Comment: @AbishankaSaha:  there is no $r$ axis in a polar plot.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $ r=k/(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))$ is equivalent to $r(cos(\theta)+sin(\theta))=k.$ Substitute $ x=rcos(\theta)$ and  $y=rsin(\theta)$ in your equation and you will get $x+y=k$ which is the equation of a straight line. For $k=0$ we get $y=-x.$ Probably if you change the window for your graph you can see the graph.

Comment: But how to to it with the Mathematica command PolarPlot[{r = f(theta)},{theta, -2pi, 2pi}]?

Answer (score -1):

If you just translate $y=x$ to polar you get $r \sin \theta=r \cos \theta$.  This is satisfied with $r=0$ and any $\theta$, which reflects the coordinate singularity at the origin.  Otherwise you can divide by $r$ and get $\cos \theta=\sin \theta$, which is satisfied when $\theta=\frac \pi 4$, \frac {5\pi}4$.  Plot that.

Comment: But how to to it with the Mathematica command PolarPlot[{r = f(theta)},{theta, -2pi, 2pi}]?

Comment: That is not possible.  This would give at most two values of $r$ because there is only two values of  $\theta$ that work.  The correct thing, as all the answers have shown, is $\theta = \frac \pi 4, \frac {5\pi}4$.  That lets $r$ be free, as it should be.